# iPhone - AdMob not appearing. Using sample code

Tags: iphone, uiview, admob, ads

I'm trying to add AdMob to my app.

I followed the instructions from the example from here: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html

with the subtle difference that I created a method and I'm calling it from the viewDidLoad

The problem is that nothing is appearing, not even an empty frame. I also tried deleting everything except the main view from Interface Builder to make sure that is not behind something but nothing is appearing.

What can I've doing wrong?

Here's my method code:

```
- (void)showBanner {

    // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height -
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"heresthestringofmyadmobid";

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                               // Simulator
                           @"heresthestringofmyphone",    // Test iPhone 3Gs 4.3.1
                           nil];

    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];


}
```

I also tried harcoding the CGFrame with 0, 0, 320, 50 to make it appear on top but nothing happened either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chompas,

You could not be getting a ad because of a low fill rate or other issue. To check if this is the issue, try enabling testMode so you will always get an ad.

You can do that with something like this:

```
GADRequest *request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
request.testing = YES;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

-David

Comment: I tried that with no luck either. I also tried with the testdevices array.
Maybe could be a setting in the admob page? I just downloaded the example code project and run it. No luck either =(

Answer (score 3):

`.testing` is now deprecated. You can instead use this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                           @"YOUR_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                           nil];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
#else
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
#endif
```

If you want test ads support in your real device and not just in the emulator,  `YOUR_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER` should be replaced by your device identifier, which you can find while your device is connected under *xCode menu > Window > Organizer > Devices*. It's a long hex number.

Comment: My only question is: why doesn't google include this code in there example. Would have saved me a lot of messing around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to set the delegate for processing events like ad recieved, ad failed, etc. I made the same mistake. [adView setDelegate: )]

Comment: I did not missed anything. The day after start working magically (?¿?¿?¿) Thanks for your answers